# Defining a custom term in a .ttl file and uploading it is extended by Fuseki with default prefix containing localhost

Tags: jena, fuseki

I am currently trying to create some initial Turtle file that I want to upload as .ttl file to my Fuseki instance.

Let's assume I have the following set of triples defined:

```
<saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2> rdf:type sosa:Platform ;
    rdfs:comment "Middle bonsai"@en ;
    rdfs:label "board bonsai middle"@en ;
    sosa:hosts 
<saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2/DFRobotCapacitiveSoilMositureSensorV1_0>;
    sosa:hosts <saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2/DS1621> ;
    sosa:hosts <saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2/BME680> .
```

It contains e.g. the "custom term" for my sensor platform that is in one of my plants

```
<saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2>.
```

When I now manually upload this .ttl file to a Dataset on my Fuseki instance all custom terms are extended to what I assume has to be a full URI by taking apparently some default server setting to add localhost:port/fuseki/Data/ as Prefix, e.g.

```
<http://localhost:3030/fuseki/Data/saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2>
```

Now I don't mind Fuseki extending my terms to "full" URIs but is there any setting that I am missing, or any kind of configuration, that defines what Fuseki uses to extend those custom terms? 
I do find localhost to be an unacceptable prefix and not very portable, so for future projects I would like to change Fusekis behaviour for such custom terms on a global level.

Tested on:

Apache Jena Fuseki 3.7.0, unpacked and started via ./fuseki start in a folder in my home directory

Java version "1.8.0_65"

Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Raspberry Pi 2

Answer (score 0):

RDF works on full URIs so they will get extended somewhere.

You can choose that in your data by adding a base declaration:

```
BASE <http://example/XYZ/>
```

(not trailing slash) then the URIs will be

```
<http://example/XYZ/saphieron/platforms/home/plants/2>
```